# SQL query with different averages for different columns for the same data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

The SQL challenge I'm working on is to build a query to display the name of an individual and their average performance over 10 iterations of data in one column and their average over 50 iterations of data in the next column. Grouped by name of course. The iterations progress in order therefore the average of the past 10 for an individual would be an average score of the 10 highest ID numbers for that individual. The raw dataset looks like this:

```
ID, Name, Score
1, Joe, 10
2, Bob, 13
3, Joe, 9
4, Kim, 6
5, Rob, 8
6, Han, 9
7, Kim, 12
```

There is about 1000 rows like this with about 50 names. The end goal is to run a query that returns something like this:

```
Name, AvgPast10, AvgPast50
Bob, 8, 10
Joe, 7, 9
Kim, 6, 10
Han, 9, 6
Rob, 7, 5
```

When I tried to do this I realized that there might be a different ways of doing this. Maybe a self join back onto itself, perhaps nested select statements. I tried and realized that I was getting in over my head. Also, my boss is a real stickler for query optimization. For some reason he despises nested select statements. If I need them then I better have a compelling reason or at least have some idea about how optimization was built into the query.

Comment: seems pivot is the solution.. but can u explain a bit

Comment: Is this `mySQL` or `MS-SQL Server`? Because the answer to this one varies accordingly.

Comment: Plz explain your expected result.

Comment: The result of the query lets us know that for example Bob averaged a score of 8 for the past 10 of his iterations and he averaged a score of 10 for the past 50 of his iterations. @AnkitBajpai

Comment: @ForgottenKahz: What does past 10 means? The last 10 or the first 10 or something else?

Comment: Past 10 == 10 highest ID numbers @Edper

Comment: And I don't think subquery (or nested select as your boss say) could be avoided here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly this one uses a nested select (or a subquery):

```
SELECT Name, AVG(CASE WHEN Rank <= 10 THEN Score END) AvgPast10,
  AVG(CASE WHEN Rank <= 50 THEN Score END) AvgPast50
  FROM (
     SELECT Name, 
     @rank := IF(@Name = Name, @rank+1, 1) as Rank,
     @Name := Name, Score
     FROM tbl
     ORDER BY Name, ID DESC
     ) A
GROUP BY Name
```

See my <kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26dbe/1)</kbd> that uses Past 3 and Past 5 for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is very small so I have used 2 and 50 below, but hopefully the process is clear regardless of numbers or how many averages

```
| NAME | AVG_2 | AVG_50 |
|------|-------|--------|
|  Bob |    13 |     13 |
|  Han |     9 |      9 |
|  Joe |     9 |    9.5 |
|  Kim |    12 |      9 |
|  Rob |     8 |      8 |


SELECT
      name
    , sum_2 / (count_2 * 1.0)   AS avg_2
    , sum_50 / (count_50 * 1.0) AS avg_50
FROM (
            SELECT
                  name
                , COUNT(CASE
                        WHEN rn <= 2 THEN score END)  count_2
                , SUM(CASE
                        WHEN rn <= 2 THEN score END)  sum_2
                , COUNT(CASE
                        WHEN rn <= 50 THEN score END) count_50
                , SUM(CASE
                        WHEN rn <= 50 THEN score END) sum_50
            FROM (
                        SELECT
                              *
                            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
                        FROM Scores
                  ) x
            GROUP BY
                  name
      ) y
ORDER BY
      name
```

I wasn't sure what you wanted to do if the number of observations is less than the quantity required (e.g. a count of 20 but average is for 50), I have used the actual count in this example.

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84cf6/2